# easyshopmakerpro5.0.3 re-install the software

Tags: reinstall, transfer

I have a program called easyshopmaker pro 5 It was produced by a company called Errol.NL a Dutch based firm. I bought all the upgrades to this program up to 5.0.3 at a fairly hefty cost. The company ceased trading in 2009 and left their customers high and dry. I am running my web shop from this software and have thus far been able to keep cleaning the code and keeping it running. My old office PC is on it's last legs and is having a hard time keeping the shop updating going. I would like to transfer the program to another more stable pc which is currently networked with the old one and both running XP home I have the downloaded .exe file for esm pro5 but the lousy ***ts made it so it has to phone home for a registration key despite me having a valid license code so I can't use the .exe to re-install. Is there any software or any fix to somehow weed the program off the one PC on to the other. I can access the old PC from the new one so It is possible to keep going like this but it's very slow.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider creating a virtual machine out of your old PC. This will avoid the need to reconfigure all of your old software on the new PC, as the virtual machine is essentially a copy of the old PC.

Virtual machines aren't exactly a beginner's topic, but it is relatively easy to do a Physical to Virtual conversion using VMWare Converter. The virtual machine would then run on top of the new PC or any other PC, and with a working backup you won't need to be concerned with hardware failures of the PC your software is running on.